# Batch file to open Ms-Dos editor and save a file

Tags: java, character-encoding, dos

I'm having a situation when I need to open a `*.dat` file and save it back through MS-DOS editor. I was thinking to create a `*.bat` file and then execute that `*.bat` file using my java application but it doesn't work.

**The reason for saving back again in DOS-editor is:**

For some reason `*.dat` file I created was not compatible with a specific software and when I save it using MS-DOS editor it simply works.

So how can I create a `*.bat` file to do this or is there other better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using ProcessBuilder?

Comment: DOS Edit works with plain ASCII text files. You should be able to write those easily without using it. It's hard to say what you need to change, though - you posted no information about what the "dat file" is or it's format, and no code that shows how you're trying to write to it. A batch file to start DOS edit is not the solution, though. It hasn't existed since Windows XP, and isn't available on Vista or Windows 7. (You also haven't really described the problem - saying "It didn't work" without any information about what "it" is you tried is like saying "My car won't start. How do I fix it?"

Comment: thanx, the dat file contains salary information of the company which is generated from the payroll software i created, that file should be encrypted using a software that the bank has given to company the problem that i can't figure out is when is created it using java and then i try to verify it using bank software it shows an error but the same file i open it using MS-dos editor and save back without doing anything it works fine! that is the problem

Comment: @KenWhite example line part of the dat file:
00007278013101350014870M G W HIMAL        23000000000000011537500SLR7510023000089072105d -----

I just use-
FileOutputStream object and then i use the PrintStream object to write to the dat file
is there somthing i should know about dat files?

Comment: There's nothing there that isn't plain ASCII text, which is why Edit works, so it's something in your code. (A `.dat` file is meaningless, because I can rename any file `something.dat`.) But it's impossible to tell you what your code is doing wrong, because there isn't any. A batch file definitely isn't the answer, though, because it won't teach you how to write to files properly; it might fix this app, but what happens when your client upgrades from WinXP and DOS Edit no longer exists? (It's not on Vista or Win7).

Comment: I would bet that it has to do with cr vs. crlf  Your code may be using the *nix format of a carriage return whereas you may need a line-feed as well.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your end-of-line characters are not compatible. Some applications expect linefeed (ascii 10), some expect carriage return (ascii 13), and carriage return followed by linefeed is probably the most common in DOS text files (ascii 13 and 10). Most applications will accept any of these, but some will only recognize one of these three as the end of a line.